# how to fix 'java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out" issue when jenkins job is building

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, automation

I have a Jenkins job which runs daily automation suite which takes nearly 3.5 hours .But I'm facing a sporadic issue which occurs time to time but not regularly as mentioned below. When this error occurred my job is hanging for several hours and tests are failing. so I would like to know the reason for this and please help me if there's a solution for this.

Error:

```
DEBUG   2019-05-15 20:45:36,121 [main] com.wso2telco.tests.apimanager.base.BasicTestObject  - Exception While Initializing browser 'openBrowser()'java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T15:28:36.4Z'
System info: host: 'ip-10-0-0-145', ip: '10.0.0.145', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-1072-aws', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
```

Comment: There is not nearly enough information here to answer this. At least provide a stack trace, and possibly more information about the actual details of the job.
Also, an automation suite taking several hours? That *appears* to be improvable, but again, with no more information, no specific answer can be given

Comment: Hi I have edited the question with whole error. there's no specif errors other than this. this error is also displaying after sevaral hours & until that build is hanging without any exceptions. when the automation suit competed without this issue it takes only 3.5 hours. but when the build is hanged with this error it takes nearly 7 hours to complete the whole suite & test failures also occuring.